# How do I achieve contrary motion in second species counterpoint?

Tags: theory, species-counterpoint

I am working on this counterpoint exercise. In 9a the second half goes down. I for the life of me can't do contrary motion without it going too high. I know I need 16th notes but there are too many. I know I need to start with the octave or unison. But from there I am stuck [image]

Comment: Using contrary motion doesn't have to mean using only contrary motion. You can adjust your counterpoint so that it makes use of contrary motion but also breaks off when necessary to stay within a reasonable range.

Comment: Where is your counterpoint? You say it goes too high. Show what you tried.

Comment: @DylanCataldo  What book is your example from please?

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the octave is definitely going to be easier.
I've submitted an example of avoiding voice crossing, but I just noticed that you think you need 16th notes. The second species is 2:1 so I would have expected eighth notes against quarters and vice versa.
Also, I had to wipe my computer recently and I rushed to install notepad which doesn't support 6/4 but luckily did have 12/8. :-(

[image]